# How to position iconbuttons closer?

Tags: flutter

I would like to make a trailing button bar at the end of my title. How can I position the buttons closer to each other?

https://szirom.hu/Fisha/so.jpg

I assume they are completily next to each other but the inner padding is too big imo.

```
ButtonTheme (
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
    child: ButtonBar (
        alignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.delete), 
                onPressed:() {
                    _deleteDialog(context, campaigns, i);
                }),
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.edit,),
                onPressed: () async {
                    ....
                }
            ),
        ],
    ),
)
```

Can I solve this with IconButtons or should I create buttons from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IconButton have is wrapped in an `ConstrainedBox` with minHeight&minWidth set to **48** ,so you'll have a modify the constrains.

something like this ...

```
 CustomIconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
              onPressed: () {},
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minHeight: 20.0,
                minWidth: 30.0,
              ),
            ),
```

The code for CustomIconButton...

```
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class CustomIconButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomIconButton(
      {Key key,
      this.iconSize = 24.0,
      this.padding = const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      this.alignment = Alignment.center,
      @required this.icon,
      this.color,
      this.highlightColor,
      this.splashColor,
      this.disabledColor,
      @required this.onPressed,
      this.tooltip,
      @required this.constraints})
      : assert(iconSize != null),
        assert(padding != null),
        assert(alignment != null),
        assert(icon != null),
        assert(constraints != null),
        super(key: key);

  final double iconSize;

  final BoxConstraints constraints;

  final EdgeInsetsGeometry padding;

  final AlignmentGeometry alignment;

  final Widget icon;

  final Color color;

  final Color splashColor;

  final Color highlightColor;

  final Color disabledColor;

  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  final String tooltip;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    assert(debugCheckHasMaterial(context));
    Color currentColor;
    if (onPressed != null)
      currentColor = color;
    else
      currentColor = disabledColor ?? Theme.of(context).disabledColor;

    Widget result = Semantics(
      button: true,
      enabled: onPressed != null,
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: constraints,
        child: Padding(
          padding: padding,
          child: SizedBox(
            height: iconSize,
            width: iconSize,
            child: Align(
              alignment: alignment,
              child: IconTheme.merge(
                  data: IconThemeData(size: iconSize, color: currentColor),
                  child: icon),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

    if (tooltip != null) {
      result = Tooltip(message: tooltip, child: result);
    }
    return InkResponse(
      onTap: onPressed,
      child: result,
      highlightColor: highlightColor ?? Theme.of(context).highlightColor,
      splashColor: splashColor ?? Theme.of(context).splashColor,
      radius: math.max(
        Material.defaultSplashRadius,
        (iconSize + math.min(padding.horizontal, padding.vertical)) * 0.7,
        // x 0.5 for diameter -> radius and + 40% overflow derived from other Material apps.
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void debugFillProperties(DiagnosticPropertiesBuilder properties) {
    super.debugFillProperties(properties);
    properties.add(DiagnosticsProperty<Widget>('icon', icon, showName: false));
    properties.add(ObjectFlagProperty<VoidCallback>('onPressed', onPressed,
        ifNull: 'disabled'));
    properties.add(
        StringProperty('tooltip', tooltip, defaultValue: null, quoted: false));
  }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you. It seems nice.I try to understand it in depth. :)